# Do all workers (child processes) process same sets of work

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm learning nodejs and I'm bit more confused with cluster module, Okay to the point, Master creates workers, in my case I'm using 32 bit windows operating system, so I'm provided with "2 workers". by considering the following simple  program

```
var cluster = require('cluster');  
var os      = require('os');
var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

console.log("start");

if (cluster.isMaster) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
      cluster.fork();
     }
 } 
 console.log(cluster.isMaster? "I'm Master":"I'm worker");
```

Output

```
start
I'm Master
start 
I'm worker
start
I'm worker
```

By googling I found Master will create worker and allocate the incoming request to the available worker. Here my question is, if two workers are available for all time then every user request will be handled twice?, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster module handles requests and routes them to a single worker.

Only one worker will ever receive a single request, even if every worker is available all of the time.

Sources and good reading material: http://stackabuse.com/setting-up-a-node-js-cluster/ and https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: Thank you for your response @evOlution